# Left Join with multiple tables question

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following tables in MySQL:

users
profile
rates

In the users table, I have the following record:

```
id: 1
name: John
status: active
```

In profile, I have the following:

```
id: 5
bio: blah blah blah
user_id: 1
```

The table rates is empty, but contains the following fields:

`id, rate, and user_id`

I am trying to use SQL to query these tables and display information about the user, their user profile (if they have one), and their rates (if one exists).  The SQL I am using is as follows:

```
SELECT user.name, profile.bio, rate.rate 
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN (profile, rate) ON (user.id = profile.user_id AND user.id = rate.user_id) 
WHERE status = 'active';
```

The problem here is that the above sql returns user.name data, but the profile.bio is null even though there is a matching user_id record in the profile table.  Seems that MySQL will not display the bio data if there is not a matching record for that user in the rates table.

If I want the SQL to display the user's name as well as their bio and hourly rate (if either one exists), how would I go about doing so?  I'm a bit confused, as I thought the above SQL should work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT user.name, profile.bio, rate.rate
FROM user
LEFT JOIN profile ON user.id = profile.user_id
LEFT JOIN rate ON user.id = rate.user_id
WHERE status = 'active'
```

You were trying to combine the LEFT JOIN logic and it was only joining if both of your conditions were true (`user.id = profile.user_id AND user.id = rate.user_id`).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with doing multiple joins in one clause, so I would tr to split up the joins, like so:

```
SELECT user.name, profile.bio, rate.rate
FROM user
LEFT JOIN profile ON user.id = profile.user_id
LEFT JOIN rate ON user.id = rate.user_id 
WHERE status = 'active';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original code was performing a left join on the `user` table and the table produced by the cross join of `profile` and `rate`.

The cross join of two tables is the cartesian product of the two tables. Specifically, it does *not* produce rows which only come from one table. Hence, when this cross joined table is left joined to `user` and with that `where` clause, you don't see the desired result.

To achieve your desired result, you need to left join multiple times.